# Get ISO-7816 response APDU has error status 0x6982 - When Initialize Update

Tags: ruby, nfc, apdu

I am writing some code to send electronic identification cards using [ISO-7816](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_7816):
If I send a "SELECT FILE" command:

```
INFO: Send command PC -> SAM: 00 a4 04 00 0f a0 00 00 00 18 43 4d 08 09 0a 0b 0c 00 00 00  
INFO: Receive from SAM -> PC: 6F 62 84 0F A0 00 00 00 18 43 4D 08 09 0A 0B 0C 00 00 00 A5 4F 73 49 06 07 2A 86 48 
86 FC 6B 01 60 0B 06 09 2A 86 48 86 FC 6B 02 02 02 63 09 06 07 2A 86 48 86 FC 6B 03   
64 0B 06 09 2A 86 48 86 FC 6B 04 02 55 64 0B 06 09 2A 86 48 86 FC 6B 04 80 00 66 0C  
06 0A 2B 06 01 04 01 2A 02 6E 01 03 9F 65 01 FF
```

After that, I send an "INITIALIZE UPDATE" command

```
-> 80 50 20 00 08 81 C3 21 A7 9D 7A DE 3E
```

And the response is

```
<- 69 82

[ERR] Smartcard::Iso::ApduError: ISO-7816 response APDU has error status 0x6982
```

I don't understand why I'm getting that response.

Comment: Could you please try 80 50 00 00 08 81 C3 21 A7 9D 7A DE 3E and share me the result?

Comment: Made some edits for legibility, marking output blocks as code.

Comment: Does adding an Le byte (i.e. sending `80 50 20 00 08 81 C3 21 A7 9D 7A DE 3E 00`) change anything?

Answer (score 1):

Well, 6982 means "access condition not fulfilled", depending on the how the card was created this could mean that that you need to verify with CHV or ADM key.